# Coq: typeclasses vs dependent records

Tags: typeclass, coq

I can't understand the difference between typeclasses and dependent records in Coq. The reference manual gives the syntax of typeclasses, but says nothing about what they really are and how should you use them. A bit of thinking and searching reveals that typeclasses essentially *are* dependent records with a bit of syntactic sugar that allows Coq to automatically infer some implicit instances and parameters. It seems that the algorithm for typeclasses works better when there is more or a less only one possible instance of it in any given context, but that's not a big issue since we can always move all fields of typeclass to its parameters, removing ambiguity. Also the `Instance` declaration is automatically added to the Hints database which can often ease the proofs but will also sometimes break them, if the instances were too general and caused proof search loops or explosions. Are there any other issues I should be aware of? What is the heuristic for choosing between the two? E.g. would I lose anything if I use only records and set their instances as implicit parameters whenever possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are right: type classes in Coq are just records with special plumbing and inference (there's also the special case of single-method type classes, but it doesn't really affect this answer in any way). Therefore, the only reason you would choose type classes over "pure" dependent records is to benefit from the special inference that you get with them: inference with plain dependent records is not very powerful and doesn't allow you to omit much information.

As an example, consider the following code, which defines a monoid type class, instantiating it with natural numbers:

```
Class monoid A := Monoid {
  op : A -> A -> A;
  id : A;
  opA : forall x y z, op x (op y z) = op (op x y) z;
  idL : forall x, op id x = x;
  idR : forall x, op x id = x
}.

Require Import Arith.

Instance nat_plus_monoid : monoid nat := {|
  op := plus;
  id := 0;
  opA := plus_assoc;
  idL := plus_O_n;
  idR := fun n => eq_sym (plus_n_O n)
|}.
```

Using type class inference, we can use any definitions that work for any monoid directly with `nat`, without supplying the type class argument, e.g.

```
Definition times_3 (n : nat) := op n (op n n).
```

However, if you make the above definition into a regular record by replacing `Class` and `Instance` by `Record` and `Definition`, the same definition fails:

```
Toplevel input, characters 38-39: Error: In environment n : nat The term "n" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type  "monoid ?11".
```

The only caveat with type classes is that the instance inference engine gets a bit lost sometimes, causing hard-to-understand error messages to appear. That being said, it's not really a disadvantage over dependent records, given that this possibility isn't even available there.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give a few specific examples where typeclasses allow to be less explicit than records? The manual is vague on the topic and thus far I didn't notice a difference. Instances seem to me not different from coercions.

Comment: Just added some more details!

Comment: A minor typo: the definition for `times_3` should be `@op _ _ n (op n n)`. Or it could be `op n (op n n)`. Otherwise Coq (v.8.4) produces the same error message as in the answer.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thanks; fixed now.